# Recursion: Two-Dimensional Grids

Tags: java

http://tinyurl.com/dy4dwf9 (Google Books. The original link was very long.)

Can someone please explain how this recursion program works? I don't understand how this doesn't cause an infinite loop. When it reaches "eraseBlob(row-1, col);," won't it keep looping back to this same method; therefore, it will repeat "eraseBlob(row-1, col);?" At the end, it says that if "image[row][col] = WHITE;" is moved to the end it will cause an infinite loop but, I don't understand how it doesn't cause an infinite loop even if it was at the beginning. I'm not completely sure what the code is trying to accomplish and I've read it multiple times. I believe it is trying to change the a cell to white as well as the cell below, above, to the left, and to the right of the original cell. Please correct me if I am incorrect.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm looks at the neighbors of each cell in turn. If the cell is black, it turns it white, and looks at the neighbors. For each black neighbor it will look at all the black neighbors, and repeat. Thus, by setting the initial cell to white before looking at the neighbors, it prevents the infinite loop (since if B is a neighbor of A, and both are black, then A will look at B will look at A will... - but if we set A to white, then when B looks at it, it will not bother with the neighbors of A, and there is no infinite loop).

Comment: Okay so say the initial cell is white then it goes to "eraseBlob(row-1, col);," which makes the row-1 cell white. What occurs after this? Will it go to "eraseBlob(row+1, col);?"

Comment: It only makes a cell white if it wasn't already, of course. And if a cell starts out black, the algorithm will visit the first neighbor, (row-1,col); assume we start with row=3, col=3. If that (2,3) is black, it will visit all its neighbors, starting with (1,3) (since when it is called, `row` is 2, not 3). And so it goes on.

Comment: So if (1,3) is black and it is changed to white, will it go to (0,3) next since eraseBlob(row-1, col); occurs after the row turns white.

Comment: I think so, yes. You could always write the code, and make it print out the cells it is visiting, if you want to make sure... Note the importance of the first line in the function that checks that you are still within the bounds of the array - without it, you would quickly get an exception.